# Reactor Netty custom channel handlers are not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, reactor-netty

I cloned the UDP Tutorial from [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/main/reactor-netty-examples/src/main/java/reactor/netty/examples/udp/qotm/QuoteOfTheMomentServer.java), with purpose of creating a simple junit test for:

1. Accept Datagram Packet and decode it into some type (currently is simple string)
2. Then after decode, it will append a string and try to send it back as response;

This is my main class

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import reactor.netty.udp.UdpServer;

public class CustomUdpServer {

private static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "7686"));
private static final boolean WIRETAP = System.getProperty("wiretap") != null;

@Test
public void build() throws Exception {
    UdpServer server =
            UdpServer.create()
                     .port(PORT)
                     .wiretap(WIRETAP)
                     .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
                     .doOnBound(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new SimpleRequestDecoder())) 
                     .doOnChannelInit((observer, channel, remoteAddress) ->
                        channel.pipeline()
                            .addFirst(new SimpleResponseHandler()));    
    server.bindNow()
          .onDispose()
          .block();
}
}
```

This is my decoder

```
import java.util.List;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SimpleRequestDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(in);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
        buf.readBytes(bytes);
        String content = new String(bytes) + " decoded";
        log.info("--> " + content);
        out.add(content);
    }
}
```

And this is my response handler

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class SimpleResponseHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        log.info(this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" started -> "+ctx.channel());
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        if (ctx.channel() != null) {
            log.info(this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" inactive -> "+ctx.channel());
        }
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        String content = String.valueOf(msg);
        
        if(msg instanceof DatagramPacket) {
              DatagramPacket packet = (DatagramPacket) msg;
              content = packet.content().toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        
        content += " responsed";
        log.info("-> " + content);
        
        ctx.writeAndFlush(content);
        super.channelRead(ctx, content);
    }
}
```

I used same UDP Client as in Github, but when i try to emit message, the attached decoder and response handler seems not invoked,

Anyone can give me suggestions or pointer ?